# (node:3966) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, server

I'm trying to fix an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED` when I make an axios call to fetch user data from mongoose query without internet connection. I've tried to wrap both the mongoose query `User.findOne()` and `mongoose.connect()` with `try catch`, but the error still remain.

> > (node:3966) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: querySrv
> >     ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster1-94jth.mongodb.net [0]     at
> >     QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:196:19) [0] (node:3966)
> >     UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> >     error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> >     without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> >     with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) [0] (node:3966) [DEP0018]
> >     DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> >     the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
> >     Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

## **FRONT-END**

client.js

```
try {                           
        const res = await axios.get('/auth/user?', {
                params: {
                    refreshToken: refreshToken,                   
                    userID: userID
                }
            }
        );                      
        console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
        if(error.toJSON().message === 'Network Error'){
            alert('no internet connection');                                
        }
    }
```

## **BACK-END**

auth.routes.js

```
auth.get(
  '/user',
  async(req, res)=>{    
    try {
      const {userID, refreshToken, uniqueDeviceID, authTimestamp} = req.query;
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({
        $and: [
            {'user_id': userID},
            {'refresh_token': refreshToken}
        ]
      });    
      res.send(existingUser);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } 
  }
);
```

server.js

```
try {
    mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true});    
    console.log('Database Connected');
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping `mongoose.connect` with `try/catch` will not work because its no doing `async/await`.

You should:

```
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true})
  .then(() => console.log('Database Connected'))
  .catch(error=> console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 2):

`try/catch` won't work with an asynchronous function without `await`
so to catch an error from asynchronous function:

```
try {
  await someAsyncFunction();
} catch (e) {
  //...
}
```

or you could use `catch` method from Promise or even use callbacks.